# Display min category price

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, woocommerce

I want to display minimum price for category. 
Basically need to loop through category product prices and return the minimum.

My code so far what I have tried:

```
        $cateegory_ids = [20,21,18];
        $query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => 20 ) );

        foreach ($cateegory_ids as $value) {
            echo(min($product->get_price()));
        }
```

Comment: you need to show us min function code

Comment: min is the php function the retuns min value in the array as far as I know

Comment: min function in php only handle single array not nested array . I think you need to write your own function to do it. I will do it in my answer

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the list of products to min function and get the min price.

```
echo(min_price($product));

function min_price($products) {
    $minPrice = null;
    foreach ($products as $oneProduct) {
        if (is_null($minPrice) || $oneProduct->get_price() < $minPrice) 
        {
            $minPrice =  $oneProduct->get_price(); 
        }
    }
    return $minPrice;
}
```

Comment: @ZygimantasKairys please accept answer if this is correct solution

Comment: it does not return nothing, tried echoing it in a span

Comment: @ZygimantasKairys then you need to var_dump me what is inside in your $product array